# Finding links in Google source code with Regex

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm trying to grab links to the 10 websites Google produces on the first page when you search for something using Regex. I'm quite new to Regex and having a lot of trouble getting this to work:

```
MatchCollection links = Regex.Matches(indexPage, @"<h3 class=""r""><a href=""\s*(.+?)\s*"" class=l", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Once I have the links in a collection I am adding them to a list here:

```
foreach (Match link in links) {
    string result = link.Groups[1].Value;
    results.Add(result);
}
```

It isn't finding any links, any help would be great thanks

Comment: suggestion: don't use regex for this

Comment: add content, from what you are trying to grab links

Comment: You haven't asked a question or specified a problem. I would suggest taking a look at the `Related` sidebar to the right.

Comment: Please consider using the HTML Agility Pack to achieve this, instead. It's a lot less fragile than any solution involving RegEx: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: and what are those websites!

Answer (score 1):

This find all urls :

```
    "#^((?#
    the scheme:
    )(?:https?://)(?#
    second level domains and beyond:
    )(?:[\S]+\.)+((?#
top level domains:
)MUSEUM|TRAVEL|AERO|ARPA|ASIA|EDU|GOV|MIL|MOBI|(?#
)COOP|INFO|NAME|BIZ|CAT|COM|INT|JOBS|NET|ORG|PRO|TEL|(?#
)A[CDEFGILMNOQRSTUWXZ]|B[ABDEFGHIJLMNORSTVWYZ]|(?#
)C[ACDFGHIKLMNORUVXYZ]|D[EJKMOZ]|(?#
)E[CEGHRSTU]|F[IJKMOR]|G[ABDEFGHILMNPQRSTUWY]|(?#
)H[KMNRTU]|I[DELMNOQRST]|J[EMOP]|(?#
)K[EGHIMNPRWYZ]|L[ABCIKRSTUVY]|M[ACDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]|(?#
)N[ACEFGILOPRUZ]|OM|P[AEFGHKLMNRSTWY]|QA|R[EOSUW]|(?#
)S[ABCDEGHIJKLMNORTUVYZ]|T[CDFGHJKLMNOPRTVWZ]|(?#
)U[AGKMSYZ]|V[ACEGINU]|W[FS]|Y[ETU]|Z[AMW])(?#
the path, can be there or not:
)(/[a-z0-9\._/~%\-\+&\#\?!=\(\)@]*)?)$#i"
```